# Is there a way for a mobile app to pay users?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, payment, mobile-application

I am just looking into mobile development, not really knowing anything about it, and I can see that there is way for users to pay small amounts in-app to the developer. However, is there any way for the developer to pay an amount to the user? I'm particularly thinking in terms of a gambling app, where the user places a bet through their phone, and then needs some way to receive their winnings - can this be done? What is the easiest way for a user to receive real money from an app?

I am mainly interested in this with respect to ios, however I would also like to know about android - I don't know what differences there might be between them.

Edit:
I appreciate the legal advice from the first two answers, which do make it clear that a gambling app is not viable as an app. However, while this is helpful on a business level, it doesn't say anything about the technical situation. Disregarding the legal aspects, my question still stands - is there any way an app can send users money? An example non-gambling use case, might be some sort of banking service that lets users deposit and withdraw small amounts through the app. I recognize that this is of no practical use, but I am still interested in knowing whether it is possible to do.

Comment: FWIK there is no API from Apple that would allow you to transfer money into their users' accounts. If you want to do payments by some other means, that's of course technically (sic!) possible (as existing casino or banking apps also show).

Answer (score 3):

Well for iOS it is going to be very difficult, not to build, but laws in every country and state.

Also the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) has real strict rules about it:

> **20.3** : It must be permissible by law for the developer to run a lottery App, and a lottery App must have all of the following
> characteristics: consideration, chance, and a prize
>
> **20.4** : Apps that allow a user to directly purchase a lottery or raffle ticket in the App will be rejected
>
> **20.5** : Apps that offer real money gaming (e.g. sports betting, poker, casino games, horse racing) must have necessary licensing and permissions in the locations where the App is used, must be restricted to those locations, and must be free on the App Store
>
> **20.6** : Apps that use IAP to purchase credit or currency to use in conjunction with real money gaming will be rejected

Answer (score 2):

Google Android has similar policy for Gambling:

Content Policy

Google's content policy is the developer of the app advertisement is displayed to the user, host or provide links to the app user-generated content, such as a display or provide links to the app applies to all content. The developer's name and registration, visit the developer's website, including the pages displayed publicly on Google Play developer account also applies to all of the content. The content of the app to comply with these policies, in addition to Google's content evaluation guidelines should be in accordance with the evaluation.

**Gaming: Google in the online casino, sports betting, lotteries, etc. that promote online gambling for cash or other content or services or products offered by the award does not allow gambling game.**